# ?Why is the integral of a step function independent of the choice of partition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

In Apostol's calculus, the integral of a step function is defined as follows:

> Let $s$ be a step function defined on the interval $[a,b]$ and let $P=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n \}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that for every $k=1,2,...,n$, $$s(x)= s_k\quad \text{for}\quad x\in(x_{k-1},x_k)$$Then the integral of $s$ is defined as $$\int_a^bs(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^ns_k\cdot(x_k-x_{k-1})$$

He then states that this definition of the integral of a step function is independent of the choice of partiton by the following reasoning:

> Suppose we change from P to a finer partition P' by inserting exactly one new subdivision point $t$, where $x_0 < t < ×$ Then the first term of the sum is replaced by the two terms $s_1\cdot(t- x_0)$ and $s_1\cdot(x_1 - t)$, and the rest of the terms are unchanged, and $$s_1(t_1-x_0)+s_1(x_1-t)=s_1(x_1-x_0)
> $$ Since we can proceed from P to any finer partition of P by adding one point at a time, all refinements of P result in the same value of the integral.

Does this reasoning really prove that all choices of partitions will result in the same value of integral? Wouldn't that require the fact that given any two partitions of $[a,b]$ over which $s$ is constant, one of them must be a refinement of the other, which I don't think is necessarily true.

Comment: Not quite. To complete the proof, it suffices that any two partitions have a common refinement. -- And indeed, the union of the two partitions is such a common refinement.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm afraid I don't quite follow. How does that imply that the integral has the same value for both of the partitions of $[a,b]$?

Comment: It is significant that the two partitions which are being compared are, by definition, partitions which define intervals that don't contain a jump - by definition they partition the original interval into subintervals on which the function is constant. This is then true for any refinement.

Comment: @MarkBennet I get that for any refinement of $P$ and $P'$, including their common refinement, the integral will be unchanged, but how does that prove that the integral has the same value for both P and P'?

Comment: Because  - as Hagen von Eitzen observes, they will have a common refinement. Each step from either partition towards the common refinement leaves the sum unchanged, and so the sum for each partition will equal the sum for the common refinement.

Comment: @MarkBennet Oh that makes sense. Thank you.